# symfony translation resource path

Tags: symfony

I can't make my translator to load a resource yams file. 
I have a file `admin.ru.yml` inside `AppBundle/Resources/config/translations/`
I have in my other bundle the following lines

```
    $translator = new Translator('ru_RU', new MessageSelector());
    $translator->addLoader('yaml', new FileLoader());
    $translator->addResource('yaml', 'admin.ru.yml', 'ru_RU', 'admin');
    $tt = $translator->trans('Category', array(), 'admin');
```

It does not load the yml file.

I even have specified in my app/config.yml file of the whole application

```
   translator:
       paths:
        - '%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/translations'
```

but with no result. I tried many paths but can't find the right way. Any suggestions of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: give me your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to rename your file @AppBundle.ru.yml, the file path is not necessary

Comment: sorry for the late response, your method works well, thank you!